# POSTing multipart/form-data to a WCF REST service: the action changes

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have a WCF Rest service:

```
      [WebHelp(Comment = "Sample description for GetData")]
    [WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate = "invoke", BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    [OperationContract]
    public string GetData( Stream input)
    {
        long incomingLength = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.ContentLength;
        string[] result = new string[incomingLength];
        int cnter = 0;
        int arrayVal = -1;
        do
        {
            if (arrayVal != -1) result[cnter++] = Convert.ToChar(arrayVal).ToString();

            arrayVal = input.ReadByte();
        } while (arrayVal != -1);

        return incomingLength.ToString();
    }
```

That I want to upload files (well, file; one at a time) to.  Using this form to test:

```
    <form method="post" action="Service.svc/invoke" >
        <input type="file" name="aFile" />
    </form>
    <input type="button" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" />
```

I can see the service receive the data, even though with the enctype of the form being set to 'multipart/form-data', only receive the element name and the name of the uploaded file.  However, if I set the enctype, I get nothing; the service is never hit.  I put a break in the code to see what was going on, and it was never reached.  Do I need to do something special in the URITemplate attribute for the 'multipart/form-data' enctype?  What else am I missing?  For the heck of it, I used Fiddler to see what was being sent to the service with each option, and there was nothing sinister looking.

Without 'multipart/form-data':

```
POST /Service4/Service.svc/invoke HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*
Referer: <my machine>/Service4/form.htm
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: okrd14144
Content-Length: 89
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

With:

```
POST /Service4/Service.svc/invoke HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*
Referer: <my machine>/Service4/form.htm
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7da1ce3aa0bd0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: okrd14144
Content-Length: 150119
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

I'm out of ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see this question? [WCF service to accept a post encoded multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354749/wcf-service-to-accept-a-post-encoded-multipart-form-data)

Comment: i did, but my understanding of WCF is weak, so i may have seen the answer and not realized it.  i'll go back and look through it again.  thanks.

Comment: solved the problem; needed to set the transfertype to "Streamed".

Comment: where do you change the transfer type to streamed?  I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: You set the transfertype (`transferMode` to be exact) in your web.config file at `standardEndpoint` inside your `webHttpEndpoint`.

Answer (score 1):

Change must be made in web.config...

```
system.serviceModel > bindings > webHttpBinding > binding > transferMode="Streamed"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the above code with no success. My web service is not being called. I have also modified my `web.config` according to: ["WCF Service to accept a post-encoded multipart form data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354749/wcf-service-to-accept-a-post-%20encoded-multipart-form-data).

All of my other service methods are working fine.