# Uploading file from Flex to WCF REST Stream issues (how to decode multipart form post in REST WS)

Tags: c#, wcf, apache-flex, rest, stream

The system is a Flex application communicating with a WCF REST web service.  I am trying to upload a file from the Flex application to the server and am running into some issues I'm hoping someone here will be able to help out with.
I'm using a FileReference in the Flex app to browse and upload the file as defined here:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/21/uploading-files-in-flex-using-the-filereference-class/

I am then receiving the file as a Stream (shows as System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.MessageBodyStream in the debugger) in the WCF REST web service (using project type of WCF 4 REST Service)

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "_test/upload")]
public void UploadImage(Stream data)
{
    // TODO: just hardcode filename for now
    var filepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\_test\testfile.txt");
    using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(filepath))
    {
        CopyStream(data, file);
    }
}
private static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    var buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
}
```

Note: CopyStream method used from this post: [How do I save a stream to a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file)

The file saves without any issues.  The issue I have is that the file contains more information than i would like.  Here are the contents of the saved file (where the source file only contained "THIS IS THE CONTENT OF THE FILE"):

```
------------ae0ae0Ef1ae0Ef1ae0gL6gL6Ij5cH2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"

testfile.txt
------------ae0ae0Ef1ae0Ef1ae0gL6gL6Ij5cH2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filedata"; filename="testfile.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

THIS IS THE CONTENT OF THE FILE
------------ae0ae0Ef1ae0Ef1ae0gL6gL6Ij5cH2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Upload"

Submit Query
------------ae0ae0Ef1ae0Ef1ae0gL6gL6Ij5cH2--
```

The contents look exactly like they are described in the Adobe documentation: 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html

Are there any facilities in C# to get the file contents from the Stream?

**EDIT (3/24 8:15 pm)**: What the Flex app is sending is a Multipart form POST.  How can I decode the multipart body data as represented by the Stream parameter and strip out the pieces of the multipart body?

**EDIT (3/25 10 am)**: some more Stack Overflow posts that are related:
[WCF service to accept a post encoded multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354749/wcf-service-to-accept-a-post-encoded-multipart-form-data)
[POSTing multipart/form-data to a WCF REST service: the action changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959890/posting-multipart-form-data-to-a-wcf-rest-service-the-action-changes)

**EDIT (3/25 10:45 am)**: Found a multipart parser that works very well:
http://antscode.blogspot.com/2009/11/parsing-multipart-form-data-in-wcf.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can achieve this with MS public API, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460088/reading-file-input-from-a-multipart-form-data-post/21689347#21689347

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Anthony over at http://antscode.blogspot.com/ for the multipart parser that works great (for images, txt files, etc).

http://antscode.blogspot.com/2009/11/parsing-multipart-form-data-in-wcf.html

Answer (score 6):

I open-sourced a C# Http form parser [here](https://bitbucket.org/lorenzopolidori/http-form-parser/src).

This is slightly more flexible than the other one mentioned which is on CodePlex, since you can use it for both Multipart and non-Multipart `form-data`, and also it gives you other form parameters formatted in a `Dictionary` object.

This can be used as follows:

**non-multipart**

```
public void Login(Stream stream)
{
    string username = null;
    string password = null;

    HttpContentParser parser = new HttpContentParser(data);
    if (parser.Success)
    {
        username = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parser.Parameters["username"]);
        password = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parser.Parameters["password"]);
    }
}
```

**multipart**

```
public void Upload(Stream stream)
{
    HttpMultipartParser parser = new HttpMultipartParser(data, "image");

    if (parser.Success)
    {
        string user = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parser.Parameters["user"]);
        string title = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parser.Parameters["title"]);

        // Save the file somewhere
        File.WriteAllBytes(FILE_PATH + title + FILE_EXT, parser.FileContents);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had some issues with parser that are based on string parsing particularly with large files I found it would run out of memory and fail to parse binary data.

To cope with these issues I've open sourced my own attempt at a C# multipart/form-data parser [here](https://github.com/Vodurden/Http-Multipart-Data-Parser)

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14514351/203133) for more information.