# Best way to consume JSON web service in .NET and requesting data using multipart POST

Tags: .net, web-services, post

I am developing an application which needs to use a web service.

Web service is running on the remote server and it accepts POST request and returns a JSON data

Here is the sample to consume service using "curl"

```
curl -F "api_key=ABCDEFGHIJKL" -F "query=@json_string.json" "http://serv/api/v4/song/identify"
```

An HTTP POST request with Content-Type "multipart/form-data" where all parameters are in the post body and the query is in the "query" parameter of the post "files"

So how could I implement client to consume the service in .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [WCF REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354749/wcf-service-to-accept-a-post-encoded-multipart-form-data/1407139#1407139) and [parse the multipart/form-data](http://antscode.blogspot.com/2009/11/parsing-multipart-form-data-in-wcf.html).

---

UPDATE:

Sorry, I misread your question. You were looking for how to write the client. In a [blog post](http://www.bratched.com/en/home/dotnet/69-uploading-multiple-files-with-c.html) of mine I suggested a sample class that allows to upload multiple files to a `multipart/form-data` enabled service along with parameters. It goes like this:

```
public class UploadFile
{
    public UploadFile()
    {
        ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public Stream Stream { get; set; }
}
```

and then a method to do the job:

```
public byte[] UploadFiles(string address, IEnumerable<UploadFile> files, NameValueCollection values)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(address);
    request.Method = "POST";
    var boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    boundary = "--" + boundary;

    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        // Write the values
        foreach (string name in values.Keys)
        {
            var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(boundary + Environment.NewLine);
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"{1}{1}", name, Environment.NewLine));
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(values[name] + Environment.NewLine);
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        // Write the files
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(boundary + Environment.NewLine);
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"{2}", file.Name, file.Filename, Environment.NewLine));
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Type: {0}{1}{1}", file.ContentType, Environment.NewLine));
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            file.Stream.CopyTo(requestStream);
            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        var boundaryBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(boundary + "--");
        requestStream.Write(boundaryBuffer, 0, boundaryBuffer.Length);
    }

    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        responseStream.CopyTo(stream);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

and finally the client:

```
using (var stream1 = File.Open("test.txt", FileMode.Open))
using (var stream2 = File.Open("test.xml", FileMode.Open))
using (var stream3 = File.Open("test.pdf", FileMode.Open))
{
    var files = new[] 
    {
        new UploadFile
        {
            Name = "file",
            Filename = "test.txt",
            ContentType = "text/plain",
            Stream = stream1
        },
        new UploadFile
        {
            Name = "file",
            Filename = "test.xml",
            ContentType = "text/xml",
            Stream = stream2
        },
        new UploadFile
        {
            Name = "file",
            Filename = "test.pdf",
            ContentType = "application/pdf",
            Stream = stream3
        }
    };

    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "key1", "value1" },
        { "key2", "value2" },
        { "key3", "value3" },
    };

    byte[] result = UploadFiles("http://localhost:1234/upload", files, values);
    // TODO: process the result
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but the server is already implemented and need some way to implement client and send the request to server without using the curl and upload the file with JSON data to server

Comment: @kdhuleshia, oh sorry, I misread your question. Please see my update.

Comment: what is the use of boundary variable in above sample

Comment: @kdhuleshia, it's a unique id that is used to separate parts in a `multipart/form-data` request.