# WCF RESTful service which accepts a file as input

Tags: wcf, rest

Being completely new to WCF, I'm trying to make a RESTful service which will accept a file (the file is usually text with comma/tab-separated values) and a delimiter as parameters, parse the file and do some calculations. Based on what I read in others posts, I assume that the WCF service needs to save the file on the server first.

EDIT: I presume the answer is something similar to the one answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354749/wcf-service-to-accept-a-post-encoded-multipart-form-data), but I'm also interested in the code not mentioned in the answer.

Here is the interface method:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "dataSets/{dataSet}/metadata?delimiter={delimiter}&format=json",
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void PostMetadataJSON(Stream dataSet, char delimiter)
    {

    }
```

And here is the method in the class implementing the interface:

```
void IMyService.PostMetadataJSON(Stream data, char delimiter)
    {
      //the delimiter is needed for splitting each line of the file  
    }
```

Can someone explain the approach to follow? I've found some examples on SO but they only got me more confused as I am completely new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use WCF's streaming support

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

Comment: Looks like all the info I need is there. Thanks.