# How to receive and process post data from a thirdparty company

Tags: asp.net

I am using a thirdparty credicard processing company. I am sending amount to pay creditcard number etc to them. They said they will postback the results such as confirmation number to a url provided by me. I have to save the confirmation number in my database. Mine is an asp.net web application. I am wondering what will be best way to provide a url. Should I give an aspx page or create a http handler which will process the data from the third party company?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a generic http handler (.ashx), because it's a lot more lightweight than .aspx.

The basic idea: use .ashx when you don't need to display a web page to end user, otherwise use .aspx.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I give an aspx page or create a http handler ... ?

Neither, use a WCF service.

[WCF service to accept a post encoded multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354749/wcf-service-to-accept-a-post-encoded-multipart-form-data)