# angularjs POST Image to WCF RESTful

Tags: angularjs, wcf, image-uploading

This Question has been asked quite a lot, I have searched Google thoroughly (mostly stack**overflow**), but none of the solutions worked for me.

I am trying to upload an image (base64) to my `WCF` Service with angularjs.

response error:

> POST http://localhost:8080/Service.svc/Method 413 (Request Entity Too
>   Large)

The main solution on most questions is allowing a bigger request in your `webconfig`:

```
  <bindings>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
         <binding  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
        <readerQuotas 
             maxDepth="2147483647" 
             maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
             maxArrayLength="2147483647"
             maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
             maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
```

But this still did not work for me.

I am not sure if the issue is caused by my `$http` request from the app:

**Base64**

```
var a = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
```

**$http**

```
 $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: ' http://localhost:8080/Service.svc/Method',
    data: "message=" + a,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
              .success(function(data) {
              console.log(data);
            })

          .error(function(data) {
              console.log("failure");
              })    

       };
```

Comment: i think you must try a multipart request instead of a simple post

Comment: Do you mean to break the string up in parts and then sending it piece by piece? @kukkuz

Comment: nope.. using `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` and post it to server just like you upload a file...

Comment: unfortunately I am still getting the same error

Comment: changing content-type alone will not work... you have to configure your /Service.svc/Method endpoint to receive a "Multipart" file and then...

Comment: I followed  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354749/wcf-service-to-accept-a-post-encoded-multipart-form-data) link it also did not make a difference is this all the appropriate steps to follow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118211/discussion-between-kukkuz-and-tjapple).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is the best solution I have found and it works perfectly.

From Client side (**Angularjs**), I followed a [uncorkedstudios.com](https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs) article, it explains how to upload an image using **Multipart/form-data**.

Then for Server side see this question [stackoverflow.com/questions/1354749/wcf-service-to-accept-a-post-encoded-multipart-form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354749/wcf-service-to-accept-a-post-encoded-multipart-form-data) It explains the sever side by using stream when receiving a request from your client.

Your Method parameter will probably look like this: `{System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.MessageBodyStream}`

For this I used a class found on [multipartparser.codeplex.com](http://multipartparser.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MultipartParser.cs).

The coding below with the class should be enough to figure out.

```
public string Upload(Stream stream)
{
MultipartParser parser = new MultipartParser(stream);

if(parser.Success)
{
// Save the file
SaveFile(parser.Filename, parser.ContentType, parser.FileContents);
}
else
{
throw new WebException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType, "The posted file was not recognised.");
}
}
```

Hope it helps.